# Background image not showing in browser

Tags: html, css

I have a question. I am pretty new to coding and I am trying to make my own website. I want to add a `background image` to my website but the image is not showing up. I have tried several things but without luck. I have added code of what I have done in my html file. I hope someone can help me with this and point me in the right direction.

This is what my html file looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Lusofly virtual.css" />
     <title>Lusofly Virtual</title>
     <style type="text/css">
body {background-color:gray;}
#mydiv {
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cbf1.png');height:200px;width:1200px;">
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:contain;
 height:200px;width:1200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   
    <div class="header">
         
         <div class="container">
             
              <div class="logo">
                  <h1><a href="#">Lusofly Virtual</a></h1>
              </div>
             
              <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">PILOT AREA</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div> 
       </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where should this image will come and where is screeshot?

Comment: You have given the relative path of your image, so it won't appear here. Also your `div` with id `myDiv` does not exist in your html.

Comment: @SahilDhir i want this image to fit my page and stay there when scrolling

Comment: Put it in the body tag , not in #mydiv.. Because #myDiv doesnot exsist in your html code.

Comment: @nashcheez can you maybe create a example with the correct way to do it

Comment: @Sennevd Added example below for your reference.

Comment: Added my answer .. This is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

On adding the `mydiv` container to your html, I can see the `background-image` being shown. Also please provide the correct path for the `background-image: url()` in your css code.

Refer code for more info:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="header">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="#">Lusofly Virtual</a></h1>
      </div>

      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PILOT AREA</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="mydiv"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i have done exactly what you with your link to the picture but it still doesnt show up i have tried chrome and firefox

Comment: You have to also add the `mydiv` container in your html. This line: `<div id="mydiv"></div>`

Comment: i have one more question the image is only behind the header and not filling the entire site do you now whats going wrong here?

Comment: You have to provide a `background-size: cover;` to your body for the image to occupy entire space. Check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Lusofly virtual.css" />
  <title>Lusofly Virtual</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: gray;
    }
    
    .header {
      background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x800.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      height: 200px;
      width: 1200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="#">Lusofly Virtual</a></h1>
      </div>

      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PILOT AREA</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `background Image` in your `body tag`

**Here is an example below:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Lusofly virtual.css" />
  <title>Lusofly Virtual</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: gray;

      background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x200.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
     
    }
    .header{ height:1000px} /* Demo height*/
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="#">Lusofly Virtual</a></h1>
      </div>

      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PILOT AREA</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code, you set the image as the background of an HTML element with ID `mydiv`, but there is no such element in your HTML code. That's why your image isn't visible.

Just add `<div id="mydiv"></div>` to your HTML code, and you should see your image :

```css
#mydiv {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cbf1.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    height:200px;
    width:1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="mydiv"></div>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="#">Lusofly Virtual</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PILOT AREA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```